# Android App login based on MongoDB Stitch, with email authentication, doesn't work after app publication on Google Play Store

Tags: android, mongodb, authentication, google-play

I have recently published an app on Google Play Store, uploading a signed app Bundle, and I let Google to sign the app with its certificate.

My app login is based on MongoDB Stitch, with authentication via email provider.

The app login works properly when installed via USB through Android Studio.

Instead, when the app is installed through the Google Play Store, the login fails.

I cannot understand where is the problem.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance,
Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Ensure you use same configurations for Release APK and Debug APK

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard.cfg'
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        multiDexEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard.cfg'
    }

}
```

2. If this didn't work try tracing your Logs I'm sure you will get what makes it not work

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the app login is still not working. This is the configuration I'm using:
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

I forgot to underline that the app is used for internal test, but I supposed it doesn't matter this fact...

Comment: I tried with your configuration and it works!!! Now, I have another doubt. I have edited my "proguard-rules.pro" file (before trying your solution) with these 3 lines:
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.* {*;}

Could the fact that I have changed the buildTypes configuration with that suggested by you make useless my editing?

Thank you so much again!

Comment: "Proguard is free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods using short meaningless names.". This is what proguard does.Changing the contents of proguard is never been a good idea.